# How to convert a .CATDrawing file to .pdf

Tags: visual-c++, catia

I want to convert a CATIA V5 file to a pdf file using vc++. How can I convert this. Am I use any third party software or dlls in my application for this operation. I am not familiar with CATIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if you have access to the Catia V5 api and likely and running instance of Catia itself. Otherwise you need Catia CAA RAID which is the full blown C++ api which is $$$.

If you have the first, it's only a few lines of code...